# How do I add font-awsome to Ionic 4 project?

Tags: ionic-framework, font-awesome, ionic4

Does anyone knows the way of adding `font-awsome` to new Ionic 4 project (currently I'm using `4.0.0-beta.15`).

Adding it to v3 is nicely explained here:

https://charlouze.github.io/ionic/2017/05/31/Ionic-3-and-Font-Awesome.html

and it works great for Ionic V3, but unfortunatelly not V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### install font-awesome

npm install font-awesome --save --save-exact

### copy.config.js

```
copyFonts: {
  src: [
    '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*',
    '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*', 
    '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
  },
```

### sass.config.js

```
includePaths: [
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
    'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',
    'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
  ],
```

### variable.scss

```
$fa-font-path: $font-path;
@import "font-awesome";
```

### home.html

```
<i class="fa fa-users"></i>
```

Please follow the above steps. That is working for me.

Comment: Thanks @Paresh, but this is a solution for Ionic 3. I wrote that this is not working in version 4: I'm getting `File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome.` when trying to `@import "font-awesome";`. Variables.scss has been completly changied since ionic 3. Also variable `$font-path` doesn't exist.

Comment: My ionic cli is CLI 4.3.1

Comment: That's fine, but you can run ionic3 or ionic4 project with this cli. Are you sure your project is ionic4?

Comment: Yes.! I updated ionic and create fresh project and implement font awesome.

Comment: I don't see these files `copy.config.js` and `sass.config.js` in my Ionic 4 project. Where are they?