# How do you add Font Awesome to Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, font-awesome, ionic4

There are a lot of tutorials and articles of how to include Font Awesome in an Ionic 3 project but I struggled finding any on how to add Font Awesome into an Ionic 4 project. So this poses the question, how do you add and use Font Awesome in an Ionic 4 project?

I have tried using the following [tutorial](https://charlouze.github.io/ionic/2017/05/31/Ionic-3-and-Font-Awesome.html) without much success. I tried following the steps outlined in the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259513/how-do-i-add-font-awsome-to-ionic-4-project) which did not work either.

Comment: It seems that you answered your own question within a couple of seconds. Any specific reason behind that?

Comment: It is a feature when you ask a question you can answer it yourself. I finally figured out how to get this right so I just thought I'd share it with the community. Since the Q&A style is available in SO I went ahead and did so.

Comment: So, I guess you are trying to create a Community Wiki Post. In that case, please read first this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts and then this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: Answering your own questions Q&A style is [absolutly allowed and most welcome on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290039/5730444), as long as both question and answer are of high quality. Making questions answered in Q&A style Community Wiki Posts is definitly not mandatory...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get Font Awesome working in an Ionic 4 project you can follow the steps below.

Firstly, you need to install all the npm packages, the first two are required but you can decide whether you need the `solid`, `regular` or `brands` icons, I will be using all of them. Go ahead and execute the following npm commands in your terminal:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Once you have done that, navigate to your `app.module.ts` in your project and add the following:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
```

Depending on which font packages you installed, add the following:

```
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

Once they have been imported at the top of your file you will need to include the `FontAwesomeModule` in your imports:

```
.....
imports: [...., FontAwesomeModule],
.....
```

Once again, depending on what icons you chose you will need to add them to the Font Awesome library that was imported earlier. Add this underneath your last import (above `@NgModule()`):

```
library.add(fas, far, fab);
```

Then navigate to the module of the page that you would like to use the fonts in i.e. `home.module.ts` and then import and add the `FontAwesomeModule`:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'
....

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FontAwesomeModule
        ...
    ],
})
```

Then finally you can use the icon in that page's HTML by inserting the following where you'd like the icon:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'graduation-cap']" slot="end"></fa-icon>
```

You can replace, `fas` with the correct library i.e. `far`, `fas` & `fab` and then the name of the icon, which in this case was `graduation-cap`.

Comment: You've written- Add this underneath your last import:
`library.add(fas, far, fab);`
What does that mean, exactly?  I can't place that within the `imports` section, nor between `imports` and `providers`, nor does it append to `FontAwesomeModule` import.  I'm a bit perplexed how to add the libraries.

Comment: @Memetican - have a look at this example. Should explain it more clearly. https://pastebin.com/zqea6T2r

Line 24 is what you want to look at.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Tachyon, I'd just figured that out myself. It's perplexing to see what looks like an instruction line sitting outside of a function code block.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a ton! @Tachyon

Comment: Great instructions.  But as of now unless you are using angular 8 you will need to install version 0.3.0 otherwise it will not work.  npm i --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.0.  The rest is the same.

Comment: does this make the app bloated?

Comment: Hi @Tachyon, I followed your steps for adding font awesome to the ionic project. I am getting a warning as: client:154 ./node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/fesm5/angular-fontawesome.js 162:55-73
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'   please help me how to rectify this issue.

Comment: @Saif.  Did you try npm i --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.0.  Check your Angular version using "ng version".  Then check here for compatibility: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome  see my comment above.

Comment: Anyone know how to get 2x icon size using <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'graduation-cap']" slot="end"></fa-icon> ?

Comment: Great implementation! How do you get the Pro icons included in this way? Thanks

Comment: I found it! You can add the pro version by replacing the prefix `free` with `pro` e.g. `@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons`

Comment: Far too complicated. Next answer is much simpler.

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command:

`npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Then, in `angular.json` append this on "styles":

```
{
    "input": "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
}
```

Comment: Very simple and functional. I also added to the scripts in angular.json as described here: https://edupala.com/font-awesome-in-ionic/

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone deals with FontAwesome PRO. I've recently bought FontAwesome pro icons and integreted them like this:

- copy the FontAwesome webfonts folder in src/assets/
- copy the FontAwesome scss folder in src/theme/
- change the $fa-font-path in _variables.scss with `assets/webfonts !default;`
- add in global.scss

  @import './theme/[YourDirectoryfontawesomeScss]/fontawesome.scss';
  @import './theme/[YourDirectoryfontawesomeScss]/solid.scss';
  @import './theme/[YourDirectoryfontawesomeScss]/brands.scss';
  @import './theme/[YourDirectoryfontawesomeScss]/light.scss';
  @import './theme/[YourDirectoryfontawesomeScss]/regular.scss';

Finally you can use them with the i tag. For example

```
<i class="fas fa-stack-overflow"></i>
```

you can find more details about the fa- classes here
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started

Comment: There is an easier way to include them with the Angular package described in the answer of @Tachyon. Simply follow this guide here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/using-other-styles.md

The additional setup that's needed for authentication and using it via npm is described here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Answer (score 2):

I was racking my brain trying to get this working with Ionic 5/Angular 10 and couldn't get it working. I figured it in the end, should anyone else require it.

**For Ionic 5/Angular 10**

Run `ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@latest` in your project folder and select the icons you require.

In `app.module.ts` add the following:

```
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; //Solid icons
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'; // Regular icons
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'; // Brand icons
```

And import `FontAwesomeModule` to the imports declarables so it looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, FontAwesomeModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

And then export a library constructor as so...

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas, far, fab);
  }
}
```

Go to the module you wish to use Font Awesome (e.g. `mypage.module.ts`) and import the `FontAwesomeModule`.

Finally in your HTML, e.g. `mypage.page.html` simply use `<fa-icon icon="home"></fa-icon>` to display an icon.

If you run in to any issues, make sure you stop Ionic first and run `ionic serve` again as this should recompile the framework.

Also take a look at https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/features.md for a full list of the features available in its usage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for the Angular user is to write ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@latest